# Angularjs HTTP Returns Error with Status 0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm new to angularjs, whenever i request get data from server i will get error status 0. Can someone point out, what wrong with my code.

- HTTPGET
- Huge Data in terms of 1000+ entries
- WCF RESTFull Services

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }

            table tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }

            table tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="client in Clients">

                    <td>{{ client.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

script

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clients.svc/getclients&clinetid=?")
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.Clients = data.clients;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(status);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: To debug, first try calling ur WCF service using POSTMAN chrome app and see if it works fine.

Comment: Ya in POSTMAN chrome app i can able to get JSON response

Comment: Are you sure the url you are requesting is correct it looks badly formatted and appears to have spelling errors. Shouldn't it be $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clients.svc/getclients?clientId=123")

Comment: I have given dummy URL here. Actuals are different they work fine in POSTMAN chrome app and also in browser